# What is the meaning of 'default value' and how can i create it in 'class'?

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments, default

This is my code that I wanted to create,

```
class RegularPolygon :

    def __init__(self):
        self.__n =3
        self.__side = 1
        self.__x = 0
        self.__y = 0
    def get_n(self):
        return self.__n
    def get_side(self):
        return self.__side
    def getX(self):
        return self.__x
    def getY(self):
        return self.__y
```

So If I run the below code to check,

```
polygon1 = RegularPolygon()

print(polygon1.get_n(), polygon1.get_side(), polygon1.getX(), polygon1.getY() )
```

It gives me 3 0 1 1 as result.

but I'd like to make a change that when I put order like

```
polygon2 = RegularPolygon(6)
print(polygon2.get_n(), polygon2.get_side(), polygon2.getX(), polygon2.getY() )
```

I want to have 6 0 1 1 for my result.

So my question is, how can I still get 3 0 1 1 when I don't put any argument in running RegularPolygon() but If put any integer such as 6, it gives me 6?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+default+parameters

Comment: `def __init__(self, n=3): self.__n = n`

Answer (score 1):

as user2896976 said just change

```
def __init__(self):
     self.__n =3
```

to

```
def __init__(self, n=3):
     self.n = n
```

This will mean n by default is set to 3 when you do not specify it, but when u specifiy it, like when u enter 6, it also gives that output too.